# objHTTP.Open unable to compile

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to send a POST URL message from MS Access VBA.  When I attempt to run the code, it tells me that is not able to compile the following statement.  Does anyone have any idea where I am incorrect in my syntax?  Thank you in advance for assistance.

```
objHTTP.Open "POST", "http://kt1.com/apiv2/Configuration.asmx", False
```

The full code is:

```
Private Sub newKT_WebService_Click()
    Dim objHTTP As String
    Dim replyTXT As String
    Dim AuthCode As String

    objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    objHTTP.Open "POST", "http://kt1.com/apiv2/Configuration.asmx", False

    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    objHTTP.send ("CallingID=12345&token=%20&domain=%20&userName=testuser&password=testpassword")

    MsgBox objHTTP.responseText

End Sub
```

Comment: That isn't a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

`objHTTP` was declared as `String`.  But later the code attempts to assign an object reference to it.  So declare `objHTTP` as `Object`.  And you must use the `Set` keyword to assign to the object variable.

```vb
Dim objHTTP As Object
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.Open "POST", "http://kt1.com/apiv2/Configuration.asmx", False
```

I'm not really familiar with `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` but hopefully those changes will allow the code to compile and do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for this insight.  The change allowed the code to compile and generate the Web Service message that I was looking for.  Thank you again for your assistance.